# Branch name in build number

Tags: git, branch, teamcity

I'm trying to put branch name into build number, but I can't find the right parameter.
I'm using build number format : `%teamcity.build.branch%.{0}`

It works, but when it trying to build default branch 'dev', teamcity names it as `<default>`.

[image]

How to fix it ?

Comment: Try `refs/heads/dev` (note that I do not know what teamcity is, so just guessing) -- just judging from the "branch specification" wording in both boxes in your UI.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195563/how-can-i-override-the-default-branch-name-in-teamcity-7-1-using-git-branching

Answer (score 12):

I was able to solve this problem by:

- In my VCS Root - using git - set my Default Branch to: master
- In my VCS Root - using git - set my Branch Specification to:

  +:refs/heads/(master)

  +:refs/heads/(release-*)

  +:refs/heads/(hotfix-*)
- Create a Configuration Paramater: BuildNumberPrefix = SomeService.%teamcity.build.branch%.release_
- Set my Build number format to: %BuildNumberPrefix%%build.counter%
- Then in my build steps add a command line step as the first step with the following script:

  set t=%BuildNumberPrefix%%build.counter%

  echo ##teamcity[buildNumber '%%t%%']

In the Team City projects listing when building the project you should see the  part of the build number get removed after the command line step is executed.  For some reason re-evaluating the BuildNumberPrefix that uses the teamcity.build.branch variable causes the default to go away and be replaced by the branch name.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps you solve the problem. Quoting the first comment from http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24147:

> We use a special branch name (`<default>`) for a reason: when there are several VCS roots with different default branches, we need a single branch name for the build. You can get a real branch name used in VCS root from build parameter teamcity.build.vcs.branch.`<canonical VCS root name>`. Search for teamcity.build.vcs.branch. on "Build Parameters" tab of the build in UI.