# Changing branch name from <default> to master

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity 2018.1.4 (build 58724), I have a couple of projects with feature branches.

In one project, the `master` branch is correctly named as `master`, whereas in another project, no matter what I try, it remains as `<default>`. The feature branches are correct.

#### Project 'A' with problem:

[image: Incorrect branch name]

---

**VCS settings:**

### [image: VCS Root settings (problem)]

#### Correct Project 'B':

### [image]

**VCS settings:**

[image: VCS Root settings (working)]

I have followed this guide: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-Logicalbranchname

and tried this answer: [Change branch name when running custom build in Teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150236/change-branch-name-when-running-custom-build-in-teamcity)

There was also a comment on another SO question (that I now can't find) that suggested removing all builds. I have tried this and it still remains `<default>`

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas for me to try, I'd be grateful if you'd share.

TIA.

---

## Update 1

The "functionality" seems to be by design. In Project 'A', I have two VCS roots, whereas Project 'B' only has one. However, I am struggling to interpret the answer given: [Branch name in build number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761887/branch-name-in-build-number/22384276#22384276)

Comment: ‘+:refs/heads/(master)’ is unnecessary, you can delete it in both projects. Another thing is I don’t know why you specify branch name in parentheses - you don’t need it

Comment: Do both your VCS roots in Project 'A' have branches with the same name? if the logical branch names do not match across both, the "default" will be used. This might be the source of your problem.

Comment: Did you find solution for this (where we have two VCR Roots). I am also struggling with this.